# Tool for cutting and joining multiple parts of a video

Tags: video, software, editing

I need a tool that allows to make multiple selections in a video and make a new video by joining all of that selections. The tool should allow to save the project, so that I could close the program, open it later, restore all selections I made before and continue. Preferably the tool should create video based on selections without any encoding settings, just using the same compression as the source file. Support for mkv required. OS: Windows 7, x86

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various tools that will do this, from the professional Adobe Premier type to Windows Moviemaker (or whatever the Live version is called now)

To be honest, a quick google will give you pages of apps from premium to FOSS. Give some of the free ones a shot, and if they don'tdo what you need, give one of the expensive ones a shot on its trial version, which most have.